# Background image not compiling into assets folder using propshaft with dartsass-rails in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-7, dart-sass, propshaft

Using Rails 7 with [Propshaft](https://github.com/rails/propshaft) and  [dartsass-rails](https://github.com/rails/dartsass-rails). I've just migrated from sassc-rails to dartsass-rails which drops sprockets as the asset pipeline library

I have a background image declared in CSS with `background-image: image-url('fancy_background.png');` the image is in `app/assets/images/fancy_background.png`

The image is not showing up in the assets folder. Other images which are declared in the HTML do get pulled in. How should I be referencing images in CSS with the "new" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was migrating from sprockets to propshaft.

Background images now need to be referenced with just `url` EG:

```scss
background-image: url('/fancy_background.png');
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/propshaft/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#3-migrate-from-sprockets-to-propshaft